# Open PDF in new browser full window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I open PDF document in new browser window?

The window should be full and withouth menu.

Just a PDF document in a clean full window with native Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I am not treating them like misbehaving children I am giving them a options. It is a document management app with few icons that open pdf in different ways. One of the icons will be full browser window, others are for download, view in dialog, view with form for editing on the side,...so way are you judging  and treating me like misbehaving children?

Comment: @Ed Guiness: You should open your eyes. In our intranet there are some people that are viewing  houndreds of document a day and they hate to choose every time to open it in a browser, download it on comp or in a app or whatever. We have a lot of users that have, imagine that, 2 monitors and like to view document in one and on the other edit the form about that document. Is this strange?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('MyPDF.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;">MyPDF</a>
```

The above link will open the PDF in full screen mode, that's the best you can achieve.

Comment: You are the only that answered my question without judging me for what i am about to do with fullscreen pdf. And i know,.. i know what i'm doing here :) But since it is just one of the views user can choose and if google does it...i guess i can't be that wrong about it. Right:) Thank You.

Comment: @moj I rarely judge other people as I'm aware that usually there are good reasons, for example client demands such feature. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @ykaragol not working means nothing is opened at all, or not full screen? Looks like Firefox simply does not support opening anything in full screen.

Comment: just fullscreen is not working. I think firefox not supporting.

Comment: @ykaragol [true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open): "Do not use. Not implemented in Mozilla. There are no plans to implement this feature in Mozilla."

Comment: Question - window.open("pdf link") taking too much time to load. I want to show loader before open this window & when window open it have to show pdf quickly. @ShadowWizardisEarForYou

Comment: @rohit should be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219755/show-loading-message-while-loading-contents-in-asp-using-jquery-ajax/14233194#14233194

Answer (score 6):

```
var pdf = MyPdf.pdf;
window.open(pdf);
```

This will open the pdf document in a full window from `JavaScript`

A function to open windows would look like this:

```
function openPDF(pdf){
  window.open(pdf);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a chance here and actually advise against this. I suspect that people wanting to view your PDFs will already have their viewers set up the way they want, and will not take kindly to you taking that choice away from them :-)

Why not just stream down the content with the correct content specifier?

That way, newbies will get whatever their browser developer has a a useful default, and those of us that know how to configure such things will see it as we want to.

Comment: I have my reasons. This will be just one of possible views in my doc management app.

Comment: No probs, @mojeime, now that you've clarified the requirements, I'll mark this answer CW since it's not as useful as I first thought :-) Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: Thank you. Answer from @Shadow Wizard works OK i just want to here some more opinions before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To download from **from a Base64 encoding** you can use the following function:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
  const bString = window.atob(data);
  const bLength = bString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(bLength);
  for (let i = 0; i < bLength; i++) {
      bytes[i] = bString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}
function base64toPDF(base64EncodedData, fileName = 'file') {
  const bufferArray = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64EncodedData);
  const blobStore = new Blob([bufferArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobStore);
      return;
  }
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobStore);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.href = data;
  link.download = `${fileName}.pdf`;
  link.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
  link.remove();
}
```

EDIT: I misread the question and had created it for downloading. Leaving the function here since it might still be useful

Comment: link.download will download the pdf not open it.