# show loading message while loading contents in asp using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, loading, message

In my asp site i'm trying to fetch user details from Active directory on page load. I like to show "loading.gif" image untill I get details. Could some help me as i'm new to jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple form of AJAX is the `.get()` method which should be enough for your needs.

First of all, add a placeholder in your HTML where the loading image will appear then when you have the contents loaded, those contents will be placed instead of the image.

For example:

```
<div id="ContentsPlaceholder"></div>
```

The jQuery code would now be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ContentsPlaceholder").html("<img src='Loading.gif' />");
    $.get("GetData.asp", function(contents) {
        $("#ContentsPlaceholder").html(contents);
    });
});
```

This will put "Loading.gif" image in the placeholder then load data from page called "GetData.asp", and when the data is available it will put it instead of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').addClass('loading');
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
      $('#wrapper').show(); // make display:none in the css.
    });
});
```

if you are using ajax then you can show it using `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()`

place it before ajax call:

```
$('#yourElem').ajaxStart(function() {
   $(this).addClass('loading');
});
```

Place this after ajax Call :

```
$('#yourElem').ajaxComplete(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('loading');
});
```

Comment: Not really. Question here mentions using AJAX and `$(window).load()` is not relevant.

Comment: I don't understand your statement. Plz can you state the question.

Comment: OK, better now and more relevant to the question at stake.