# Open PDF Stream in New Window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, stream, window.open

How do you open a new window that displays the streamed response of an AJAX request?

Answer (score 15):

Other similar questions presuppose a scenario where the response has a [defined url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735968/open-pdf-in-new-browser-full-window), other answers are kind of [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401006/show-a-pdf-stream-in-a-new-window).

For modern browsers, you use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) you can can call [blob() on the returned response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) and then use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility) to create a temporary url that you can open as normal with [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Full example is something like

```
fetch(urlThatReturnsDataOpenableByBrowser)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(data => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data)))
```