# How to open link in default browser from PDF with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to open the link "www.google.com" from PDF file in Adobe Acrobat with JavaScript. I try "windows.open()", but it works if file has extension ".html", not pdf. Help me, please.

Comment: Try this link. It's helpful to you - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735968/open-pdf-in-new-browser-full-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735968/open-pdf-in-new-browser-full-window)

Comment: @OmkarJadhav, thanks. But I want opening pdf file in Adobe Acrobat with opening link in default browser, not opening pdf in browser)